# Category VS logger tags in jboss-log4j.xml

Tags: jboss, log4j, jboss5.x

What should we use in jboss-log4j.xml in order to turn on/off traces for our product - "category" or "logger" tag?

By default JBoss uses "category" in jboss-log4j.xml.
But as far as I know "category" is deprecated and "logger" should be used instead.
Why JBoss uses deprecated "category" tag in a new product?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Habit, I suspect. I still to use `category` also. It behaves exactly the same as `logger`, there really is no difference.

Comment: Looking at the javadoc, the Category class is now deprecated in favor of Logger. In the configuration, I would expect both would be supported.

Comment: it is **bad** habit to continue to use depreciated features.

Answer (score 1):

`category`   in the log4j.xml (not limited to jboss-log4j.xml) is common practice and its not deprecated. What got deprecated is the `Category Class` as in usage of `Category` in code like,

```
Category category = Category.getInstance('something');
```

In log4j.xml, both category and logger can be used. Probably the newer code will have the `logger` in log4j.xml. Old way is `category`.

Comment: Okay, but what about the difference between them? And also `category` seems to have `level` and `priority` as acceptable properties: what is the difference between those?